# Blocked users should not be received notification using mod_apns.erl in ejabberd

Tags: ios, push-notification, xmpp, block, ejabberd

I am using ejabberd 16.09 version, for notification use mod_apns.erl file to the mod_apns module.

I am receiving offline message using this module and also for getting notification from blocked users message.
i.e. UserA and UserB online.
UserA has blocked to UserB.
UserA can't send a message but when UserB sends message UserA getting that sent message notification.

So, Can you please help me out for how to prevent the notification from blocked users.

Answer (score 0):

Did you fill a bug report in the mod_apns module bug tracker? Their developers will have much more clue where the problem is...

Comment: Thank you. Where to report it on mod_apns module bug tracker? Can you please send me link?